# Wann hat man aufgehört, im Perfekt Hilfsverben wegzulassen?

Tags: history, modal-verb, perfect-tense

In der früheren Literatur war es üblich, das Hilfsverb im Perfekt oder Plusquamperfekt wegzulassen. Hier ist ein Beispiel (aus *Reichtum*, einer Kurzgeschichte von Arthur Schnitzler) in dem das letzte Wort *hatte* unausgesprochen bleibt:

> Er sah sich mit jenen ärmlich gekleideten Leuten an einem Tische sitzen und Karten spielen, wie er es so oft getan.

Ich habe den (vielleicht falschen) Eindruck, dass dieses Weglassen heute nicht mehr auftritt und möchte wissen, seit wann und warum der Brauch verschwunden ist.

Comment: Navid Kermani hat mich bei meiner heutigen Lektüre damit ebenfalls überrascht, und sein Buch (Große Liebe) ist aus diesem Jahr! Also 2014. ( Es scheint, ich schreibe aus der Zukunft, so alt wie dieser Thread schon ist).

Comment: Das scheint heutzutage die Ausnahme und eine Eigenheit (natürlich nicht unbedingt ausschließlich) Kermanis zu sein: In Kermanis „Sozusagen Paris“ (2016): „ Während ich fremden Menschen meinen Namen ins Buch schreibe, vergleiche ich die Frau, die nicht Jutta genannt werden möchte, ein ums andere Mal mit dem Mädchen, das ich in der Raucherecke angehimmelt.“

Comment: Im Schwedischen gibt es eine entsprechende Konstruktion ohne Hilfverb, die - soweit ich das beurteilen kann - noch heute lebendig ist.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Der Eindruck täuscht nicht – diese „afinite Konstruktion“ findet man nur noch sehr selten. Nach Sekundärliteratur konnte ich bisher nur oberflächlich suchen. Google Books liefert zu `afiniter Konstruktion` schon mal ein paar Treffer. Admoni geht in *„Die Entwicklung des Satzbaus in der deutschen Literatursprache des 19. und 20. Jahrhunderts“,* Berlin 1987, ab S. 114 ausführlicher auf diese syntaktische Form ein, von ihm habe ich die meisten folgenden Details. Von Google Books abgesehen, dürften Online-Quellen zu diesem speziellen Thema eher rar sein.

Was ich gefunden habe, ist in etwa Folgendes: Vermutlich stammt diese grammatikalische Praxis aus der Kanzlei-, also der Juristensprache (16. Jh.?) und wurde später in andere Literaturgattungen und den breiteren Schriftgebrauch übernommen. Während juristische Texte im 19. Jahrhundert eine höhere sprachliche Genauigkeit anstrebten und dabei auch auf grammatikalische „Vollständigkeit“ achteten, hat sich die afinite Konstruktion in der Prosa länger halten können. Das Schnitzler-Zitat (von 1891?) ist ein wunderbares Beispiel dafür, finde ich.

Warum diese besondere Syntaxvariante so selten geworden ist, kann man nur vermuten. Ich nehme an, dass dieses Phänomen grundsätzlich als Ausnahme von der Regel der vollständigen Ausformulierung empfunden wurde, also als – „rechtfertigungsbedürftige“ – Abweichung, nicht als Normalfall. Gerade der gezielte Einsatz in der Prosa, etwa um den Nebensatz noch stärker zurücktreten zu lassen, impliziert ja einen **bewussten** Einsatz dieses Stilmittels. Zudem nehme ich an, dass die afinite Konstruktion schon zu Schnitzlers Zeiten nicht mehr „modern“ klang, noch weniger im 20. Jahrhundert. Aus juristischen und diplomatischen Texten war sie da wohl schon verschwunden, Naturwissenschaftler hatten keinen Grund, sie im technischen Bereich einzuführen; und in der Prosa klang sie wahrscheinlich nach 18. und 19. Jahrhundert, also antiquiert. Man würde heute einen anderen Effekt erzielen als jenen, der vielleicht im 18. und 19. Jahrhundert verfolgt worden war.

Comment: Ein Schriftsteller, der die Konstruktion bewußt systematisch eingesetzt hat, um Nostalgie über eine vergangene Zeit auszudrücken, war Stefan Zweig, und zwar in den 1920er Jahren; schon damals war sie also stark antiquiert.

Comment: @KilianFoth Aha, deshalb ist sie mir so vertraut, dass ich sie seit langem vermisse!

Comment: Nicht nur in den 20er Jahren benutzte Zweig die Konstruktion sondern auch, und ganz besonders, in der _Welt von Gestern_, die er in 1942 beendete (und das Manuskript am Tag vor seinem Selbstmord seinem Verleger überreichte).

Comment: Wie kann eine seltene, überraschende Konstruktion geeignet sein, etwas zurücktreten zu lassen. Das Gegenteil sollte der Fall sein, besondere Aufmerksamkeit.

Comment: @userunknown Für diejenigen, die aufpassend auf die Grammatik lesen und mit dieser Konstruktion nicht bekannt sind, scheint deren Verwendung eher den Gegeneffekt zu verursachen (der sogar dazu führt, dass man sie auf Stack nachforscht, haha). Für all die anderen tritt aber wahrscheinlich der Nebensatz zurück wegen Verkürzung.