# Warum gibt es hier kein Hilfsverb: »wo er noch nie geatmet«

Tags: sentence-structure

Aus *Der Zauberberg* von Thomas Mann:

> Dieses Emporgehobenwerden in Regionen, wo er noch nie **geatmet** und wo,
>   wie er wußte, völlig ungewohnte, eigentümlich dünne und spärliche
>   Lebensbedingungen herrschten, — es fing an, ihn zu erregen, ihn mit
>   einer gewissen Ängstlichkeit zu erfüllen.

Sollte es vielleicht *»atmete«* sein?

Comment: Same as in your other question, this is a poetic ellipsis as well. Works from almost 100 years ago are not good teaching material to learn the present day grammatical rules of a language, unfortunately.

Comment: @Annatar Ich erfahre auch gern über die Geschichte von Sprachen und sehe, wie sie sich entwickelt haben.

Comment: Das ist sehr lobenswert. ;)

Comment: Die Form nennt man *afinite Konstruktion*. Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/wann-hat-man-aufgehört-im-perfekt-hilfsverben-wegzulassen

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wann hat man aufgehört, im Perfekt Hilfsverben wegzulassen?](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/wann-hat-man-aufgeh%c3%b6rt-im-perfekt-hilfsverben-wegzulassen)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Der Grund ist einfach die Tatsache, dass Deutsch eine lebende Sprache ist, deren Regeln sich im lauf der Zeit verändern.

Der Roman »Der Zauberberg« ist im Jahr 1924 erschienen, und Thomas Mann hat in diesem Roman offenbar ganz bewusst ein literarisches Deutsch verwendet, das man einerseits als gehoben, andererseits aber auch als ein wenig antiquiert bezeichnen kann.

Das Fehlen von Hilfsverben findet man nämlich auch in den Werken z.B. von E.T.A. Hoffmann, der rund 100 Jahre vor Mann lebte. Nur war es zu Hoffmanns Zeit noch allgemein üblich, zumindest in der gehobenen Sprache auf Hilfsverben zu verzichten.

Zu Manns Lebzeiten fand gerade ein schleichender Übergang statt. In einigen Regionen galt man als besonders gebildet und belesen, wenn man Hilfsverben wegließ, in anderen Regionen sah man das bereits anders.

Wenn ich mich nicht irre, verwendete auch Franz Kafka (ein Zeitgenosse von Thomas Mann) in seinen Büchern Sätze, in denen der manchmal die Hilfsverben wegließ.

---

Wenn du liest, um Deutsch zu lernen, dann sollte dir bewusst sein, dass sich Deutsch, wie jede lebende Sprache, ständig verändert. Je älter ein Buch ist, desto stärker weicht es in der Grammatik, im Wortschatz und in der Rechtschreibung von jener Sprache ab, die man in aktuellen Werken findet.