# Ellipse der Hilfsverben in Nathan der Weise (I.2, 227-236)

Tags: grammar-identification, literature

Ich brauche Hilfe, um einen Auszug (I.2, 227-236) aus [Nathan der Weise](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nathan_der_Weise) zu verstehen.

**Hier ist [der Auszug](http://www.zeno.org/Literatur/M/Lessing,+Gotthold+Ephraim/Dramen/Nathan+der+Weise/1.+Akt/2.+Auftritt) (I.2, 227-236):**

(Nathans Tochter wurde von einem Tempelritter gerettet. Dieser Templer selbst war vom Sultan Saladin begnadigt worden. Nathan spricht mit seinem Diener, Daja.)

> 227 - Laß mich! – Meiner Recha wär'
>
> 228 - Es Wunders nicht genug, daß sie ein Mensch
>
> 229 - Gerettet, welchen selbst kein kleines Wunder
>
> 230 - Erst retten müssen? Ja, kein kleines Wunder!
>
> 231 - Denn wer hat schon gehört, daß Saladin
>
> 232 - Je eines Tempelherrn verschont? daß je
>
> 233 - Ein Tempelherr von ihm verschont zu werden
>
> 234 - Verlangt? gehofft? ihm je für seine Freiheit
>
> 235 - Mehr als den ledern Gurt geboten, der
>
> 236 - Sein Eisen schleppt; und höchstens seinen Dolch?

Was mich interessiert, ist die [Ellipse](https://wortwuchs.net/stilmittel/ellipse/) von einigen Hilfsverben. Hier ist, wie ich diese Hilfsverben hinzufügen würde:

> 227 - Laß mich! – Meiner Recha wär'
>
> 228 - Es Wunders nicht genug, daß sie ein Mensch
>
> 229 - Gerettet **[[hat]]**, welchen selbst kein kleines Wunder
>
> 230 - Erst retten müssen **[[wird]]**? Ja, kein kleines Wunder!
>
> 231 - Denn wer hat schon gehört, daß Saladin
>
> 232 - Je eines Tempelherrn verschont **[[hat]]**? daß je
>
> 233 - Ein Tempelherr von ihm verschont zu werden
>
> 234 - **[[hat]] Verlangt**? **[[hat]]** gehofft? ihm je für seine Freiheit
>
> 235 - Mehr als den ledern Gurt geboten **[[hat]]**, der
>
> 236 - Sein Eisen schleppt; und höchstens seinen Dolch?

Vier Fragen:

- (a) ist meine Lesart korrekt ? Vornehmlich habe ich Schwierigkeiten, die Verse 229-230 zu verstehen.
- (b) warum sind einige - nicht alle, siehe Verse 231 - Hilfsverben verschwunden? Für die Verse #234 ist es klar, daß das Tempo sich beschleunigt. Aber was ist mit den anderen Versen?
- (c) Wie klingen diese Ellipsen : sind sie in der gesprochenen Sprache verbreitet? Oder in der Literatursprache?

Comment: Siehe auch https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/wann-hat-man-aufgeh%c3%b6rt-im-perfekt-hilfsverben-wegzulassen und die dort verlinkten Fragen.

Comment: #231 vermeidet undeutliche Syntax, etwa "gehört hat". #230 empfehle ich alternativ "hat/wird retten müssen". Ist das hier ein Literaturzirkel? Ich vote *close*.

Answer (score 7):

Das ist eine archaische *afinite* Form der Partizipverwendung. Sie ist heute an sich nicht mehr verbreitet und würde als altmodisch oder (außerhalb der Lyrik) sogar falsch angesehen.

Bis ins frühe 20. Jahrhundert waren solche Formen durchaus üblich - Thomas Mann z.B. schrieb gerne so.

Ich würde das nicht unbedingt als Ellipse bezeichnen - damals hat keinem wirklich was gefehlt, heute werden solche Konstruktionen nur noch in der (Boulevard)presse verwendet:

> Mord im Fahraddschlauch! Mörder durch das Ventil entkommen!

oder in stehenden Ausdrücken

> Hans, Müller, geboren am 20.10.1970, hat heute Geburtstag gefeiert.

aus rein grammatikalischer Sicht ist so eine Konstruktion also nicht unbedingt falsch.

Comment: *Friedensvertrag im Nahen Osten geschlossen* schreibt auch die seriöse Zeitung in ihrer Überschrift, nicht nur die Boulevard-Presse. Das ist ein gängiges Mittel zur Verdichtung von Überschriften. - *Hund von Mann gebissen* - Eine Auslassung von *hat* ist aber nicht üblich: *Berg Maus gekraißt* wäre zu verwirrend für die Leser. Darum schreibt man *Berg hat Maus gekraißt".

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann ... das könnte jetzt erklären, warum ich das "Boulevard" in Klammern gesetzt habe.

Comment: Sowohl der Perfekt- als auch der Passivcharakter des Partizip II liegen bei dieser Verwendung völlig offen. Man kann sich ein *ist*, *wird*, *bleibt* dazudenken, damit wird es zu einem Prädikativausdruck. *Hat* gehört nicht zu dieser Gruppe, es hebt das Passiv auf und man müsste ein handelndes Subjekt benennen.

Comment: *Merkel sieht Beziehungen gefährdet* ← was wir als *Perfekt* oder *Passiv* bezeichnen ist im Grunde genommen nur ein Spezialfall solcher Prädikativausdrücke, bei denen entweder der Passivcharakter (mittels *haben*) oder der Perfektcharakter (mittels *werden*) unterdrückt wird.

Comment: +1: Abkehr von verbreiteter Alles-ist-eine-Ellipse-Erklärung.

Comment: Was ist denn bei *Mord im Fahrradschlauch* ausgelassen?

Comment: @DavidVogt Nix. Ohne den Teil funktioniert der Witz aber nicht.

Comment: Ich gebe hier mal -1, weil nicht auf die einzelnen Punkte des Fragestellers eingegangen wurde. *Afinite Partizipverwendung* ist ein merkwürdiger Ausdruck. Das Partizip ist immer infinit, ihm fehlt nichts. Dem Satz fehlt etwas. Daher paßt *afiniter Nebensatz* oder allgemeiner *afinite Konstruktion*.

Comment: @DavidVogt Dem Satz fehlt nach damaligem Sprachgebrauch überhaupt nichts. Heute mag das anders sein.

Comment: @tofro Ich weiß nicht, woher der Widerstand gegen den Begriff "fehlen" kommt. Das ist nicht abwertend, sondern rein deskriptiv: Ein erwartetes finites Verb tritt nicht auf. Alternative Begriffe wären *Ersparung* oder *Auslassung*. – Eine eindeutig wertende Aussage findet man dagegen bei [Gottsched](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb10583647_00452.html?zoom=1): *Bey der völlig und längst vergangenen Zeit, lasse man das **Haben**, **Seyn**, und **werden** nicht ohne dringende Noth, und erhebliche Ursache weg; damit man nicht dunkel und unverständlich schreibe.*

Comment: Gottsched ist hier interessant, weil er in einer Zeit schreibt, in der die Konstruktion sehr verbreitet war. Und trotzdem fand zumindest er sie *dunkel und unverständlich*. Das widerspricht zu einem gewissen Grad der Haltung, daß den Menschen damals nichts gefehlt habe.

Comment: @DavidVogt eher fand er Sie latent missverständlich, wenn unbedacht gebraucht -- dächte ich. In "Denn wer hat schon gehört, daß Saladin je eines Tempelherrn verschont?" dagegen ist die Offenheit nützlich und demnach auch heute noch weit verbreitet, vielleicht nie afinit gewesen.

Comment: @DavidVogt Du führst *einen* auf, dem nachweislich was gefehlt hat. Die Existenz von massenhaft Werken, die solche afiniten Konstruktionen verwenden, beweist wohl, dass es wesentlich mehr Leute gab, denen eben nichts gefehlt hat. Deine Argumentation ist einigermaßen unlogisch. G.s Aussage nach haben dann von Luther bis Goethe, Fontane bis Mann alle "dunkel und unverständlich" geschrieben. Nunja.

Comment: @tofro Was soll denn eigentlich *afinit* bedeuten, außer daß ein finites Verb *fehlt*? abwesend ist?

Answer (score 4):

**a) Lesung weitgehend richtig**

Deine Lesung / Ergänzung des Hilfsverbs ist richtig bis auf Zeile 230, wo ich [[hatte]] einsetzen würde. Dies folgt m.E. aus der Logik des Ablaufs des Erzählten (das ist hier also ein semantisches Argument, kein syntaktisches): *Meiner Recha wär' es Wunders nicht genug, dass sie ein Mensch gerettet hat, welchen selbst kein kleines Wunder erst retten müssen hatte.*

In Prosa-Deutsch könnte man sich noch fragen, ob man nicht *retten gemusst hatte* sagen möchte, was eine andere valide Form ist. Allerdings sind beide Formen mit Plusquamperfekt so umständlich, dass man in der Praxis eher sagen würde *retten musste*, auch wenn es den Zeitablauf nicht ganz präzise wiedergibt.

**b) Grund: Rhythmus**

Der Hauptgrund fürs Auslassen oder auch Verwenden der Hilfsverben wird sein, den Versrhythmus zu wahren. Hinzu kommt aber, dass die Auslassung nur zulässig (gebräuchlich, üblich) ist bei nachgestelltem Hilfsverb:

> Der Mann der einen Fisch gefangen [[hat]], hat [!] für sein Mahl recht wohl gesorgt.

Dies ließe sich nicht umkehren zu [FALSCH!]: *Der Mann, der einen Fisch gefangen hat, für sein Mahl recht wohl gesorgt.*

**c) Nur in der Schriftsprache**

In der gesprochenen Sprache (damals wie heute) sind solche Ellipsen vollkommen unüblich. Man kann natürlich so sprechen, aber dann klingt es entweder altmodisch poetisch oder ironisch. - Siehe dazu H. Schölnasts widerprechende Meinung im Kommentar unten, sowie meine Entgegnung dazu.

Comment: Der Versrhythmus ist natürlich auch ein Grund, aber nicht der Hauptgrund. Den Hauptgrund hat tofro in seiner Antwort genannt. Das ist die afinite Form der Partizipverwendung, die vor 200 bis 300 Jahren ganz allgemein üblich war, auch in der Prosa. Wenn du die Werke von E.T.A. Hoffmann liest, wirst du bemerken, dass dort nur diese Konstruktion vorkommt. Das war in der gehobenen Sprache bis in die Anfänge des 20. Jahrhunderts üblich. Tofro hat bereits Thomas Mann als Beleg genannt, ich möchte noch Franz Kafka hinzufügen. ...

Comment: ... Wie tofro schon gesagt hat, sind das keine Ellipsen. Das ist einfach nur altes, aber korrektes altes Deutsch. Und die in c) aufgestellte Behauptung, das wäre auch damals vollkommen unüblich gewesen, ist leider falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Zur Üblichkeit in gesprochener Sprache: Es kann durchaus sein, dass ich mich hier irre. Wie jedoch sollten wir feststellen, was wirklich gesprochen wurde? Tonaufnahmen von, sagen wir, 1820 gibt es nicht; wortgetreue Transkripte von mündlicher Sprache auch nicht. Du magst noch Polizeiprotokolle anführen, die sind jedoch stets schriftsprachlich stilisiert. Am ehesten könnte man noch Dialekte heute anschauen unter der Hypothese, dass sich deren Gebrauch vielleicht wenig verändert hat (?), aber dort sind Hilfsverb-Auslassungen so weit ich sehe nicht anzutreffen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Zur "Hauptgrund"-Frage: Ja, die afinite Partizipialverwendung war weit verbreitet. Das sagt aber nichts über den Grund für die Auslassung. Und ich behaupte einmal (zumindest zum Test der Hypothese), dass egal ob in Vers- oder Prosatexten, der Grund ein ästhetischer war, nämlich die Suche nach schönerem Rhythmus. (Auch Prosasätze haben Rhythmus.) Was sollte sonst der Grund sein? Man könnte noch sagen, ein Schreiber will Zeit und Tinte sparen. Das mag in bürokratischen Texten sein, aber sicherlich nicht in Texten, die mit künstlerischer Intention erstellt wurden.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Wenn wir nichts über die gesprochene Sprache wissen können - wie du argumentierst -, wie kannst du dann in deinem Post eine Aussage darüber treffen?

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Wieso spricht die Erklärung "afinite Partizipverwendung" dagegen, dass es sich um eine Ellipse handelt? Und: Du scheinst mir hier einen Gegensatz zwischen "Ellipse" und "korrekt" aufzumachen. Wieso kann etwas nicht gleichzeitig eine Ellipse und korrekt sein?

Comment: Punkt b) ist wichtig, es geht um Nebensätze. Zu c) sagt Behaghel (*Dt. Syntax* III, § [1162a](https://reader.digitale-sammlungen.de/de/fs1/object/display/bsb11023510_00508.html?zoom=1)): *Der lebendigen Mundart und der Umgangssprache ist die Ersparung fremd.*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast  Was können wir über mündlichen Ausdruck in früheren (tonaufnahmelosen) Zeiten sagen? Wir können immerhin versuchen, aus analogen Kontexten der Gegenwart Schlüsse zu ziehen. Nachdem die afinite Verwendung des Partizips auch heute nicht im mündlichen Verkehr vorkommt und auch Dialekten fremd ist (siehe oben D. Vogt zu Behagel) scheint mir die Vermutung, dass es auch früher so war, näherzuliegen als die umgekehrte Vermutung.

Comment: interessanter Ansatz in b) finde ich "wer (gefangen [hat) gesorgt]" aber interessanter, schön verschachtelt.