# Das Hilfsverb ist optional?

Tags: auxiliary-verb

Mir ist schon mehrmals aufgefallen, dass das Hilfsverb (haben / sein) in einigen Fällen nicht immer im Satz zu finden ist. Ich konnte kein Muster finden, um zu verstehen, in welchen Fällen diese weggelassen werden können.

Einige Beispiele:

- sofern nicht anders angegeben
- sofern nichts anderes vereinbart ist
- sofern nicht anders festgelegt

Ich habe die drei Fomulierungen gesehen, die aber nicht immer mit einem Hilfsverb "sein" begleitet werden. Ich würde erwarten, dass das Verb in solchen Fällen immer vorhanden sein muss, doch sieht es so aus, als ob diese weggelassen werden dürfen...

Ein weiteres Beispiel:

```
- Dein Code hat immer noch Tabs statt Leerzeichen.
- Sorry, falschen Editor benutzt.
```

Den Satz ohne "habe" wurde von einem Muttersprachler geschrieben.

```
Solange Farbe neutral [ist?], erneut auftragen und schleifen, bis die oberfläche stabilisiert und glatt ist.
```

Gibt es denn die Regel, die vorschreibt, in welchen Fällen man die Hilfsverben benutzen nicht kann, nicht darf und/oder eigentlich nicht sollte?

Answer (score 6):

Das Phänomen, bei dem das Hilfsverb im Perfekt weggelassen wird, nennt man *afinite Konstruktion*. Sie war schon einmal [Thema bei Stackexchange](https://german.stackexchange.com/q/1590/25241). Kurzum: Die afinite Konstruktion ist keine grammatische Regel, sondern ein Stilmittel, das seinen Ursprung wohl in der Kanzleisprache hat. Man findet sie heute nur noch selten. Schriftsteller, die sie gern eingesetzt haben, waren zum Beispiel Arthur Schnitzler, E. T. A. Hoffmann, Thomas Mann und Stefan Zweig.

---

**Zusatz:** In den Kommentaren wurde angemerkt, dass es sich bei den (ersten drei) Beispielen aus der Frage nicht um die afinite Konstruktion handeln könne, da neben dem Hilfsverb zum Beispiel auch noch das Objekt weggelassen wurde oder da der Konnektor *sofern* hier eine besondere Rolle spiele. Diesen Argumentationen kann ich nicht folgen. Die afinite Konstruktion ist „definiert“ als eine Einsparung des finiten Hilfsverbs in Verbletztstellung – Punkt! Sie tritt also in Nebensätzen auf, die beispielsweise durch Relativpronomen oder Subjunktoren – also unter anderem durch *sofern* – eingeleitet werden. Und was in den Beispielen sonst noch passiert, etwa wenn zusätzlich noch ein Objekt eingespart wird, ist für die Feststellung, dass eine afinite Konstruktion vorliegt, irrelevant. Bei den letzten Beispielen liegt in der Tat keine afinite Konstruktion vor. Aber um die scheint es in den Kommentaren ja nicht zu gehen.

Comment: Das passt leider nicht. Das Besondere hier ist der Konnektor (_sofern_), und darin unterscheiden sich die Beispiele grundlegend. Die hier beschriebene Struktur ist in der Gegenwartssprache - im Gegenteil zu dem dort beschriebenen Phänomen - überaus frequent. _Herr Mayer kann, obwohl [ ] krank [ ], an dem Ausflug teilnehmen._ / _Sofern [ ] fristgerecht gestellt [ ], kann dem Antrag stattgegeben werden._ Etc. An der Stelle nur kurz ein Link auf https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/2526. Grüße!

Comment: (* im Gegenteil -> im Gegensatz)

Comment: Wenn man die Beispiele oben vergleicht, sieht man, dass da nicht einfach ein Hilfsverb weggelassen wurde. In den Beispielen gibt es innerhalb der Konstruktion auch kein Objekt, wenn kein Hilfsverb vorhanden ist, sondern ein Adverb: "sofern **nichts anderes** vereinbart wurde" / "sofern **nicht anders** vereinbart"

Comment: Zum Zusatz: Ich habe nicht behauptet, dass es sich hier nicht um "afinite Konstruktionen" handelt (wohl eine Nebenbezeichnung für Auxiliar-Ellipsen). Ich sage: Das Beispiel dort (_wie er es so oft getan_) verweist auf ein anderes sprachliches Phänomen als _sofern nicht anders angegeben_. Natürlich werden in beiden Fällen Hilfsverben weggelassen, das sehe ich auch. Aber während die reine Auxiliar-Weglassung in _wie er es so oft getan_ (die Subjektstelle ist da übrigens noch besetzt, anders als in _sofern nicht anders angegeben_) wohl unbestritten veraltet ist, ... (1/2)

Comment: ... trifft man Kopula-Subjekt-Weglassungen im internen Konnekt bestimmter Subjunktoren jeden Tag mehrmals an. _Dieses_ Phänomen ist ganz und gar nicht veraltet. Es ist auch gut dokumentiert, vgl. nur den Kriterienkatalog von Breindl/Donalies unter https://grammis.ids-mannheim.de/systematische-grammatik/2528. Insofern bringt es uns m.E. nichts, das Beispiel hier mit dem anderen zu vermischen und das hier gleich mit für veraltet zu erklären. (Werde schauen, ob ich heute/morgen noch die Zeit für eine eigene Antwort finde. Wie es scheint, ufert die Frage leider mittlerweile zunehmend aus.) (2/2)

Answer (score 0):

Eine gute Antwort habe ich nicht, aber zu viele Bemerkungen für einen Kommentar. Die Fälle gleichen sich nicht und können auch nicht einfach als Weglassung des Hilfsverbs analysiert werden.

Im einen Fall fehlt der gesamte Satzanfang. Interessanterweise wird sogar *den* weggelassen, obwohl es zu *falschen Editor* gehört.

> (Ich habe den) falschen Editor benutzt.

Im anderen Fall fehlen in einem adverbialen Nebensatz sowohl das Subjekt als auch das finite Verb.

> sofern (S) nicht anders festgelegt (V)
>   wenn (S) gewünscht (V)
>   sobald (S) bekannt (V)
>   obwohl (S) wenig beachtet (V)

Über die Bedingungen, unter denen diese Verkürzung möglich ist, weiß ich nichts.