# past participle with seemingly missing auxiliary verb

Tags: past-participle

Die Bourgeoisie, wo sie zur Herrschaft **gekommen**, hat alle feudalen, patriarchalischen, idyllischen Verhältnisse zerstört. (Communist Manifesto, section 1, par 14)
"The bourgeoisie, wherever it **has come** to power, has  ..."

Why is there not an auxiliary "ist" with "gekommen" in the relative clause (if that is what it is) introduced by "wo"?

Comment: See also https://german.stackexchange.com/q/59497 and the posts linked there.

Comment: The "ist" is implicit. It's quite stylish, and I see this sometimes in older texts, or in poems. Actually, we can not distinguish in this style, whether the writer meant "ist" or "war".

Comment: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/54936/das-hilfsverb-ist-optional is neither the same topic nor the right language.