# Handelt es sich bei der Auslassung des Verbs „haben“ um eine Brachylogie oder einen anderen rhetorischen Begriff?

Tags: grammar-identification, ellipsis, rhetoric

Im Jahre 1981 veröffentlichte der deutsche liberale Politiker [Eugen Richter](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eugen_Richter) ein Werk mit dem Namen „[Sozialdemokratische Zukunftsbilder](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sozialdemokratische_Zukunftsbilder)“. Gegen Ende des Buches ([hier zu finden auf der PDF-Seite 57](https://ia803402.us.archive.org/22/items/sozialdemokratische-zukunftsbilder-richter-html-2b-7566fbe-30d-589d/Sozialdemokratische_Zukunftsbilder_Richter.pdf)) steht folgendes Zitat:

> […] Auch ich muß mich verfluchen, daß ich so viele Jahre hindurch dazu beigetragen habe, Zustände, wie wir sie in diesen Monaten erlebt `[]`, heraufzubeschwören. Ich that es aber nur, weil ich davon eine glücklichere Zukunft für Kinder und Kindeskinder erhoffte. Ich verstand es nicht besser. Aber werden mir meine Söhne es je vergeben können, dass ich mitgewirkt `[]` zu den Ereignissen, deren Folgen ihnen die Mutter und die Schwester geraubt und unser ganzes Familienglück vernichtet haben?

Die leeren eckigen Klammern `[]` drücken aus, dass hier etwas ausgelassen worden ist. Was könnte man hier einsetzen und welche Namen trägt dieser rhetorische Begriff?

Als ich bei Wikipedia zuerst nach [Ellipse](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse_(Sprache)) gesucht habe, wurde ich hier später auf den Begriff [Brachylogie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brachylogie) aufmerksam gemacht. Dieser würde aber vermutlich eher auf die zweite Auslassung innerhalb des Zitates zutreffen und weniger auf die erste.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/wann-hat-man-aufgeh%c3%b6rt-im-perfekt-hilfsverben-wegzulassen

Comment: Nein, eine Elipse ist das nicht, und eigentlich auch gar keine stilistische Form, sondern ganz normales Deutsch. Es ist zu einer stilistischen Form *geworden*, nachdem es aus der Mode gekommen war - wenn man nämlich extra "altertümlich" klingen wollte.

Answer (score 3):

Wie [hier](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/wann-hat-man-aufgeh%C3%B6rt-im-perfekt-hilfsverben-wegzulassen?noredirect=1&lq=1) korrekt angemerkt wurde, ist das eine sogenannte "afinite Konstruktion". Sie war immer schon ein Mittel, das Gesagte stilistisch hervorzuheben, der "Normalgebrauch" der Sprache schrieb dagegen seit jeher den Einsatz des Modalverbs vor. Als die Praxis generell etwa im 18. bzw. 19. Jahrhundert aufhörte, wurde die Formulierung (selten) als Stilmittel eingesetzt, um Nostalgie oder Altertümlichkeit anzudeuten.

Auch in der Lyrik wird die Konstruktion verwendet:

> Ich flehe dich um drei Tage Zeit,
> bis ich die Schwester dem Gatten gefreit. [habe]
> (Schiller, Die Bürgschaft)

> Wer einmal frei
> vom großen Wahn
> ins leere Aug
> der Sphinx geblickt, [hat]
> (Morgenstern, Der Wissende)

Wenigstens in der Lyrik existiert die Auslassung nicht nur für das Partizip Perfekt, sondern auch das Präsens:

> Das an ihr hängt, dem Busen nah,
> Und ihre Rosenwangen lecket
> Und das oft viele Reize sah,
> Die meinem Späherblick verstecket. [sind]
> (Novalis, An Laurens Eichhörnchen)

Comment: Es wird wohl auf immer Herrn von Hardenbergs Geheimnis bleiben, ob das im letzten Beispiel tatsächlich Präsens ist - Es könnte auch ohne weiteres (und die korrekte Zeitfolge deutet daraufhin, wegen *sah*) Perfekt sein.

Comment: @tofro: Consecutio temporum hat hier wohl weniger Einfluß als Bedeutung. Das Präsens wird auch für statische Zustände verwendet ("Bremen liegt an der Küste." heißt nicht, daß es nur heute so ist, sondern immer) und falls Novalis ausdrücken wollte (was zumindest im Bereich des Möglichen liegt), daß das, was er sehen wollte, schon immer versteckt war und auch jetzt ist, dann wäre das Präsens unabhängig vom Tempus des Hauptsatzes korrekt.