# The present perfect in songs

Tags: lyrics, past

I was hearing one of my favourite songs "Ode an die Freude" and I noticed something quite curious about the lyrics. Consider the following line:

> Deine Zauber binden wieder
>
> Was die Mode streng geteilt

Shouldn't there be a sein/haben somewhere in the second line...? Or is the geteilt not used in the sense of pst perfect?

Comment: It’s an “afinite Konstruktion” as I learned here: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1590/wann-hat-man-aufgeh%c3%b6rt-im-perfekt-hilfsverben-wegzulassen

Comment: All questions that I’ve found are in German, so not a duplicate.

Comment: You are right. I didn't consider the language of answers

Comment: Your heading seems wrong. There's no *abuse*.

Comment: "Ode to Joy" in the English title. The poem is by Schiller, then Beethoven set the poem to music in his 9th Symphony. Beethoven's version differs from the original btw, in particular it includes a preamble: O Freunde, nicht diese Töne!/Sondern laßt uns angenehmere anstimmen,/und freudenvollere. I try not pay too much attention to differences between modern German prose and poetry or anything written before 1900; poets take liberties with the language and the language has changed over time.

Comment: "geteilt" is past participle, BTW, not present.

Answer (score 6):

Leaving out a finite *haben* or *sein* is a stylistic device often used in poetry and songs. You can also find it in prose before the 20th century, and even in academic texts.

You can use it nowadays if you want to mark a character as literate and a bit old fashioned. In songs, it's used for prosody and it's still very common though.